# How long until I get out of bed?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose I have two independent alarm clocks which I set right before I go to bed. Their ring times are exponentially distributed with rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Whenever alarm 1 goes off I immediately reset both alarms, but if alarm 2 goes off I actually get up.

How long do I stay in bed? Am I right in saying that alarm clock one is redundant with respect to bed staying time?

Comment: Let $Y$ and $X$ be the first times alarm 1 and alarm 2 go off. Can you compute $P(Y > c | Y > X)$? Does it equal $P(Y>c)$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right.  This comes down to the fact that exponential random variables are *memoryless*.  The idea is that a "reset" exponential has the same distribution as a conditioned one.  Here's the math:

Let $X$ be exponential with rate $\lambda$, and let $b > a$.  Then $$\mathbb{P}(X > b | X > a) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X > b)}{\mathbb{P}(X > a)} = \frac{e^{-\lambda b}}{ e^{-\lambda a}} = e^{-\lambda(b-a)} = \mathbb{P}(X > b - a).$$

In other words, if we know that alarm 2 hasn't gone off after $a$ minutes, then the probability it won't go off after another $b - a$ minutes is the same as the probability a reset clock won't go off for $b - a$ minutes.  This proves that resetting doesn't make a difference for the distribution of alarm 2.